# JavaScript three array elements match-check by loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Unsure how to setup loops correctly to check whether elements in a targeted array matches any two other arrays or matches them both:

The code:

```
let test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let test2 = [7,8,9,10,11]
let check_test = [2,7,10,12]

for (var testa in test) {
  for (var test2a in test2) {
     for (var check_testa in check_test) {
        #Triple for-loop trying to loop all arrays
        if (check_testa == testa && check_testa != test2) {
           console.log("Match TEST")
        } else if (check_testa != testa && check_testa == test2) {
           console.log("Match TEST2")
        } else if (check_testa == testa && check_testa == test2) {
           console.log("Both match!")
        } else {
           console.log("None match!")
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Basically the code supposed check whether the elements in array `check_test` matches any elements in the other two arrays `test` and `test2`.

If the element(of `check_test`) match elements in only one of the two other arrays, then print "Match [test] or [test2]!". If both match then print "Both Match!" and finally if both no match then print "None Match!"

And the output for this is supposed to be:

```
2 Match TEST!
7 Both Match!
10 Match TEST2!
12 None Match!
```

So how to set loops correctly to make it match-check then print the elements and output only once? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop. Use `.includes` to check which of the other arrays the value being iterated over exists in (if any), and [don't use `in` when iterating over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) (and if you were to use `in`, at least access the value in the array with bracket notation, rather than using the index only).

```js
let test1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let test2 = [7,8,9,10,11];
let check_test = [2,7,10,12];
for (const num of check_test) {
  const one = test1.includes(num);
  const two = test2.includes(num);
  if (one && two) {
    console.log('both');
  } else if (!one && !two) {
    console.log('neither');
  } else if (one) {
    console.log('one');
  } else {
    console.log('two');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer is fine, but would point out that there is still a nested loop, just a prettier one, obscured by a built-in function `includes`.  Still  O(n^2).